# CachedIntrospectionResults - Not strongly caching class because it is not cache-safe

Tags: java, spring, playframework, javabeans

Does anyone know what does this warning mean?

```
o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults - Not strongly caching class because it is not cache-safe
```

It is a warning logged in my play framework application. It seems has something to do with this [class](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults.html) from spring but I can't find more info...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the message is thrown from the `org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults#forClass` method of the `spring-beans` library which uses the `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils#isCacheSafe` method of the `spring-core` library for checking whether the specified class is cache-safe (it checks whether the class is loaded by the same class loader as the CachedIntrospectionResults class).

`CachedIntrospectionResults#forClass:`

```java
/**
* Create CachedIntrospectionResults for the given bean class.
* @param beanClass the bean class to analyze
* @return the corresponding CachedIntrospectionResults
* @throws BeansException in case of introspection failure
*/
static CachedIntrospectionResults forClass(Class<?> beanClass) {
    ...
    if (ClassUtils.isCacheSafe(...)) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
        logger.debug("Not strongly caching class [" + beanClass.getName() + "] because it is not cache-safe");
    }
    ...
}
```

`ClassUtils#isCacheSafe:`

```java
/**
* Check whether the given class is cache-safe in the given context,
* i.e. whether it is loaded by the given ClassLoader or a parent of it.
* @param clazz the class to analyze
* @param classLoader the ClassLoader to potentially cache metadata in
* (may be {@code null} which indicates the system class loader)
*/
public static boolean isCacheSafe(Class<?> clazz, @Nullable ClassLoader classLoader) {
...
```

Maybe the sources of [CachedIntrospectionResults](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults.java) and [ClassUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java) classes will clarify the problem.